# AngularJS controller function response

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, scope, mean-stack

my controller below returns a json through service as below:

```
.controller('googleFormsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window, Userr,$timeout,$location) {
        // SEND THE HTTP REQUEST
        var url;
        var externalWindow;
        // MAKE API REQUEST for Authorization
        $http.get('/api/googleAuth').then(function (response) {
            url = response.data;
        });

        this.googleAuthentication = function () {
            externalWindow = $window.open(url, "Please Sign in with Google", "width:350px,height:350px");
        };
        // Close Authorization and set credentials
        window.onmessage = function (info) {
            externalWindow.close();
            // Get the URL
            var urlCode = info.data;

            // Get pure code of user
            var idx = urlCode.lastIndexOf("code=");
            var code = urlCode.substring(idx + 5).replace("#", "");

            // GET ALL FORMS
            Userr.getCredentials(code).then(function (res) {
                $scope.forms = JSON.stringify(res.data);

            });
        };

    })
```

As it is seen above, I get all forms within the callback of the request, and I need to use them in order to put into options menu in another page like below:

```
<div>
    <h2> Google Forms </h2>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="selectForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <br>
        <!--The Forms should be displayed below dynamically-->
        <h5>Select Google Form</h5>
        <select class = "form-control" ng-model="model.id"
                ng-options="form.id as form.name for form in forms" >
        </select>
        {{model.id}}
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">OK</button>
</div>
```

That is why **I have to access them out of function scope.** My data from res.data is like that:

```
[{
            "id": "1o3FUAJAPsS2m93_ECkVtLcYbMaaWHk6UGHIFG-6lpyA",
            "name": "Normal Form"
        }, {
            "id": "1QB5MHWtXytLUqGHUH1Ac-V9fS7hHlCqSWXjq2iFz1Zk",
            "name": "Parti Davetiyesi"
        }];
```

**How can I export this data out of function scope?** Any help or hint is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does the code stringify the data object? The `ng-option` directive takes an object not a string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anytime you need to make something globally available, or at least available to multiple controllers, you need to use a factory or service.

Services and factories are singletons, meaning that once they are instantiated, they remain in memory for the lifetime of the application.

(In fact it's always a good idea to implement some sort of caching into your services so that you are not making unecessary calls.)

So, the result of the `$http` request can be assigned to a service variable:

```
        // GET ALL FORMS
        Userr.getCredentials(code).then(function (res) {
            $scope.forms = JSON.stringify(res.data);
            // to make this data availbale everywhere,
            // simply add the result to the service itself
            Userr.forms = res.data;
        });
```

Now, in every controller that injects your `Userr` service, you have access to this data:

```
// in another controller
$scope.forms = Userr.forms;
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention, however I Tried your approcah but it did not work. Could you please look at my controller: https://pastebin.com/ytmhPin0

Comment: Where is the code for your service `Userr`? That is relevant code